# Full width HTML5 Video with max height issues

Tags: css, responsive-design, html5-video

I'm literally pulling my hair out with this issue so any help will be much appreciated.

I've a HTML5 `<video>` which I want to be: -

1. **Full Width** - controls should always be 100% of the width of the screen.
2. **Max Pixel Height** - height of video doesn't increase more than the pixel height of the video.
3. **Resizes horizontally to bounds** - when the browser is resized (while keeping ratio).
4. **Resizes vertically to bounds** - when the browser is resized vertically (while keeping ratio).

This is what I have so far: -

```css
html, body, .page {
  height: 100%;   
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
video { width: 100%; height: auto;  }
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<div class="video-content">
 <video style="max-height: 320px;" controls> <!-- width="320" height="200" -->
        <source src="http://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

So this satisfies (1) i.e. controls are the full width of the screen and (2) the height of the video isn't bigger than the resolution height of the video (`320` pixels).

[image]

When the browser is resized horizontally then (3) is also satisfied.

[image]

However, there are issues when resizing vertically as follows: -

[image]

Note the scroll bar (as opposed to the video resizing).

So if I update the CSS from

```
video { width: 100%; height: auto;  }
```

... to ...

```
video { width: 100%; height: 100%;  }
```

... then all of the conditions are satisfied except (3) this time i.e. there is a gap between the controls and the actual video: -

[image]

If I could combine a `100%` and `auto` into the `height` attribute of the `<video` tag this would probably fix it.  Could hack something together in JavaScript but my gut feeling is that I'm doing something stupid.

Thanks in advance for any tips / help!

Answer (score 5):

If i understand, this is the solution:

```css
video {
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  max-height:100%
}

.video-content {
  height:100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="video-content">
  <video controls> <!-- width="320" height="200" -->
    <source src="http://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  </video>
</div>
```

Comment: It's very close except that condition 2 `Max Pixel Height - height of video doesn't increase more than the pixel height of the video.` isn't satisfied. i.e. the height of the video increases over `200px`.

Comment: This solution does work for anyone in general trying to limit the height of the video.

Comment: This works until you want to add any content below or above the video, like say title text in an `h1`. Then the `height:100vh` will allow the bottom border of the video to extend below the viewable window by whatever the height of your `h1` is. You can change `height:100vh` to `85vh` or whatever, but if your `h1` height is variable (maybe because of text wrap or something else), you cannot properly account for it. Is there no way to prevent the bottom border of a video from overflowing its container?

Answer (score 1):

change your video tag with this:

```
    <video style="max-height: 100%;" controls>
```

Comment: That makes the video the "full height" of the browser, I want the max height of the rendered video to be no more than the actual resolution height of the video, in this case 320px.

Comment: not downvoting but just notifying readers that this is not a complete solution. you have to wrap the video tag with a container to force styles. There is a better solution here on this thread.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution which does exactly what I want, still don't know if this is the best solution or not but posting here anyway.  The solution is simply to add a `@media` query: -

```
@media screen and (max-height: 320px) {
    video { height: 100%; }
}
```

The media query swaps the max-height of `320` pixels for `100%`, only if the browser goes under a certain size.